# Likelihood ratio test for one sided test for two variances

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio

Let $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}$ be a random sample from $N\left(\mu_X, \sigma^{2}_X\right)$ and $Y_{1}, \ldots, Y_{m}$ be a random sample from $N\left(\mu_Y, \sigma^{2}_Y\right)$. Assume $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ are known for simplicity. We would like to test $H_{0}: \sigma^2_X = \sigma_Y^2$ vs $H_{1}: \sigma^2_X > \sigma_Y^2$. How to derive a likelihood ratio test (LRT). Are there any references?

Comment: Google variations of 'Likelihood derivation of F test' to see online references. I don't know the exact level of your course, but one promising possibility is [this](http://users.stat.umn.edu/~sandy/courses/8311/handouts/ch06.pdf) around p111. Be sure to put 'Likelihood ratio' in the search and look for class notes from major universities. // Suggest for this level, you should flee at the first sign of ads or a video.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Likelihood Ratio Test for Common Variance from Two Normal Distribution Samples](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/541681/likelihood-ratio-test-for-common-variance-from-two-normal-distribution-samples)

Answer (score 1):

**Comment.** I won't do the theoretical part. However, sometimes it helps to see a likelihood test in action
when trying to interpret the results of the ratio to get the
test statistic and the critical value.
So here is R output with some remarks:

**Fictitious two-sample data** with sample variances and their F-ratio:

```
set.seed(2021)
x1 = rnorm(20, 50, 7);  x2 = rnorm(40, 100, 15)

var(x1); var(x2)
[1] 58.0856
[1] 252.5335
var(x1)/var(x2)
[1] 0.2300114
```

**Output from test** of $H_0: \sigma_1^2/\sigma_2^2= 1$ against one-sided alternative
$H_a: \sigma_1^2/\sigma_2^2 < 1.$ Note: your test is right-tailed, mine is left-tailed.

```
var.test(x1, x2, alt="less")

        F test to compare two variances

data:  x1 and x2
F = 0.23001, num df = 19, denom df = 39, p-value = 0.0005719
alternative hypothesis: 
 true ratio of variances is less than 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.0000000 0.4669059
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
         0.2300114
```

**Critical value.** Reject $H_0$  at the 5% level if the F-ratio is *smaller* than critical value $c = 0.4926,$
shown as a dotted red line in the figure below.

```
qf(.05, 19, 39)
[1] 0.4926291
```

Note: Usually, the likelihood
ratio makes it clear what test statistic to use, and whether to reject for
large or small values of the test statistic. However, you need to identify the
distribution of the test statistic and use printed tables or software to
find the numerical value of the critical value.

The observed value of the F-statistic is 0.2300, shown as a solid black line in the figure.

**The P-value** of the test
is the area under the density curve to the left of the solid black line.
Ordinarily, you cannot find exact P-values by looking at printed tables.
(P-values are 'creatures' of the computer age.)

```
pf(0.230, 19, 39)
[1] 0.0005717457  # agrees with printout up to rounding error
```

[image]

R code to make the figure above:

```
hdr = "Density of F(10,30)"
curve(df(x, 19, 39), 0, 3, lwd=2, col="blue", 
         ylab="Density", xlab="F", main=hdr)
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=0, col="green2")
 abline(v = 0.4926, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
 ab;ine(v = 0.230, lwd = 2)
```

**Using printed tables.** For a right sided test at the 5% level, the critical value will be in the right tail
of the distribution $\mathsf{F}(19, 39)$ at $2.0960.$ You should be
able to find this value is a printed table of F-distributions. [Maybe you'll have to approximate, using degrees of freedom 20 and 40, if 19 and 39 are left out
to save space.]

```
qf(.95, 19, 39)
[1] 2.095977
```

By contrast, the left-sided critical value is *not shown in many printed F-tables.* But it is easy to get in R.

```
qf(.05, 19, 39)
[1] 0.4926291
```

Note: To get a left-sided critical value from tables you may have to take the reciprocal of a value
from a printed table, with the degrees of freedom *reversed.*

```
qf(.05, 19, 39)
[1] 0.4926291      # not available in some printed tables
1/qf(.95, 39, 19)  # DF reverse: available in table
[1] 0.4926291      # ... reciprocal of available value
```

One reason I'm showing a left-sided test is to have motivation to show you this identity.

Comment: Maybe the answer should also show, the derivation of the likelihood-rato-test, and show why the F-test is equivalent to a likelihood ratio test.

Comment: I guess that would  require showing the LR test in detail, which I chose to leave for OP. But it is done in the reference in my comment.